# Solving/graphing derivative equations

Tags: python, syntax-error, modeling, differential-equations

I am a student and am trying to figure out how to solve differential equations with python but I am very confused. I am also getting a syntax error on the fourth to last line, and I am not sure why. This model is supposed to show the progression of a virus.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# function that returns dT/dt

# initial condition

T = 1
V = .001
I = 0

def model(t,T,I,V):
    β = 10**-5
    δ = 4
    p = 2*(10**6)
    c = 4
    dTdt = -β*t*V
    dIdt = (β*T*V) - (δ*I)
    dVdt = (p*I) - (c* V)
    return dTdt, dIdt,dVdt


# initial condition

T0 = 1
V0 = 10**-3
I0 = 0

# time points
t = np.linspace(0,25)

# solve

V = odeint(model,t,V0, args = (T0,I0)
# plot results
plt.plot(t,V)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('V(t)')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Is it missing a parenthesis in the previous line? `V = odeint(model,t,V0, args = (T0,I0)`.

Answer (score 0):

The state vector is one single argument in the ODE function. So you have to replace its first line with

```
def model(Y,t):
    T,I,V = Y
```

and correct the integrator call to

```
Y = odeint(model,[T0,I0,V0],t)
T,I,V = Y.T
```